# List all polynomials of degree 3 in the field of integers mod 2 $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

List all polynomials of degree 3 in the field of integers mod 2 $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.
In $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$, the only elements are 0,1, since everything above 1 equals either 0 or 1 in mod(2).

I think the answer would be: $x^3+x^2+x+1$, $x^3+x^2+x$, $x^3+x^2+1$, $x^3+x+1$, $x^3+x^2$, $x^3+x$, $x^3+1$, and $x^3$.

Or is this one of those trick questions where the answer is "none" because 3 isn't an element of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

Comment: No, it is not a trick question - you are allowed to have 3 as an exponent in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ :)

Comment: Also note that any such a polynomial has the form $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb Z_2$. As you have $2$ choices for each letter, there should be 8 polynomials, which is what you got...

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. Not a trick question. Just because 3 is not an element in $\mathbb Z_2$ doesn't mean there are no *polynomials* of degree 3 (or any other degree).